# onMarkerClick event is not working with ClusterManager

Tags: android, google-maps

I know there are a few other questions in the same category, but nothing has solved my problem.

I am using ClusterManager to cluster Markers using Google Maps API guide (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering).

Problem: I am using addItem() on the ClusterManager object, passing location, together with Title and Snippet. However, when I click on the marker, nothing appears. I have simplified the code to figure out the problem but was unable to solve this issue.

Here is my simplified code:

MyItem.java:

```
package com.example.android.testmarker.model;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterItem;

public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
private final LatLng mPosition;
private String mTitle;
private String mSnippet;

public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
}

public MyItem(double lat, double lng, String title, String snippet) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mTitle = title;
    mSnippet = snippet;
}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() { return mPosition;}

public String getTitle() { return mTitle;}

public String getSnippet() { return mSnippet; }
}
```

MarkerclusterActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android.testmarker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.testmarker.model.MyItem;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterItem;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager;


public class MarkerclusterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreated called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onMapReady callback triggered");
        mMap = map;

        //restricting users panning to Vancouver dt area. 
        LatLngBounds limit = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng( 49.268642, -123.148639),
                new LatLng( 49.300045, -123.095893));
        //Add limit to our map
        mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(limit);

        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(13.0f);

        //Set the initial camera to the center of downtown (where it says Vancouver)
        LatLng initialLocation =  new LatLng( 49.282733f, -123.120732f);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(initialLocation, 13.0f));

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, map);
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.        
        addItems();
    }

    private void addItems(){
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(49.2831205, -123.1107811,
                "Location54", "Garbage"));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(49.2839704, -123.1116479,
                "Location 55", "Garbage"));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(49.2831205, -123.1135884,
                "Location 58", "Garbage"));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(49.2816015, -123.1101502,
                "Location 60", "Garbage"));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(49.2810562, -123.1083306,
                "Location 69", "Garbage"));

        //Add some locations a bit further from the ones above
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem( 49.283200, -123.126951));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem( 49.283633, -123.136453));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem( 49.285686, -123.130786));

    }
}
```

Right now when I click on the marker, the camera centers around the marker, and the default GoogleMaps buttons(direction, googlemaps buttons) appear at the bottom right (meaning the marker click event was triggered); however, it never shows the Title/Snippet.

NOTE: I have tried this in the demo app of Google Maps API and it works without adding anything else; however, since their demo was using way too many classes, I was unable to pin point the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it all working. 
There was nothing wrong with the code; after trying every possible scenario, I just created a new App from scratch and added the code, and it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Android development!  I've been doing this a long time, and I enjoy finding posts like this when I can't figure something out.. "start over from scratch" fix huh??  lol

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Here is how I did it: 
> KOTLIN version
> ```

```
//adding items to cluster 
        mCustomerClusterManager.addItems(customerAroundMeItems)
        mEquipmentClusterManager.addItems(equipmentAroundMeItems)
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
 this.googleMap = googleMap

    //Step 1
    
        val markerManager = MarkerManager(googleMap) // your googleMap instance
    
     
    //Step 2


    mEquipmentClusterManager = ClusterManager(activity, googleMap,  markerManager)
    mCustomerClusterManager = ClusterManager(activity, googleMap, markerManager)

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(markerManager)
    googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this)

    //Step 3
    
    val rendererCustomer =CustomerAroundMeMapPinsCluster(activity,googleMap, mCustomerClusterManager)
    
    val rendererEquipmentRental = EquipmentAroundMeMapPinsCluster(activity,googleMap,mEquipmentClusterManager)

    //Step 4
    
       

     mCustomerClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Customer Cluster click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    onClusterClick(it)
                    return@setOnClusterClickListener false
                }
    mCustomerClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Customer item click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                
                return@setOnClusterItemClickListener false
            }

    mEquipmentClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Equipment Cluster click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return@setOnClusterClickListener true
        }
        mEquipmentClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener {
            // there is a ticket for this
            Toast.makeText(context, "Equipment item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            
            return@setOnClusterItemClickListener false
        }
 

    mCustomerClusterManager.renderer = rendererCustomer
    mEquipmentClusterManager.renderer = rendererEquipmentRental


}


     override fun onCameraIdle() {
            mEquipmentClusterManager.cluster()
            mCustomerClusterManager.cluster()
    
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have actually not really touched this project in a while. I am enjoying Koltin these days, so I'll give it a try